# C execlpe() can't invoke Python code

Tags: python, c

This is what I've tried:

**p.py:**

```
import os

print os.environ['path']
print os.getenv('R')  # ERROR: can't obtain
```

**C code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
  char* vars[] = {"R=r", NULL};

  if (execlpe("python", "python", "./p.py", NULL, vars) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't run script: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }
}
```

run environment: winxp + tdm-gcc-4.9.2.exe + python-2.7.9.msi.

run c code,

```
report error: access denied
```

**Update 2016-03-27:**

if replace

```
if (execlpe("python", "python", "./p.py", NULL, vars)
```

with

```
if (execlpe("python", "python", "./p.py", NULL, NULL)
```

run c code OK. But how pass environment var "R"?

Comment: You destroyed your `PATH` variable, which means that `execlpe` will probably be unable to find **any** executables

Comment: I searched execlpe to find the man page. Oddly enough, *this question* is the first DDG result for execlpe.

Comment: @immibis execlpe on msdn redirects to _execlpe, which is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59y63c61.aspx, but yeah that syscall is not on the mac os and linux machines I checked.

Comment: @emil.p.stanchev I wasn't asking for a link; the *second* search result was actual documentation. I was just surprised.

Comment: Where is the text "report error" coming from?  Or did you get "Can't run script:"?

Comment: Try passing the full path to the executable. If that helps, it is as Petesh said, i.e. that without the `PATH` environment variable it can't find the executable.